# Creating an object of an abstract class - Error

Tags: java

I have an abstract class called `A`.

```
public abstract class A {
 protected String name;
 A(String name){
  this.name=name;
 }
}
```

The above class is in the package `com.goog.product.demo` package

Now from another package i need to load some test data, by creating an object as shown below;

The following class is in the package `com.goog.product.test` .

```
public class Test {

 public void loadData(){
  A a =new A("NAME");
 }
}
```

But, I end up getting an error:

> Cannot instantiate the type A

The reason is because; you can't create an object of abstract class. Is there any other way I could load some test values?

Comment: Maybe you should just make `A` _not abstract_?

Comment: Yes, but this is only for testing purposes.. i just need to load some data and see if it works. I will also keep this test class in the project to run future test cases

Comment: So?  You make a class abstract if, and only if, subclasses need to implement some more methods, or if you want to make it impossible to instantiate.  Which applies here?

Answer (score 6):

Abstract classes cannot be instantiated. You should read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) for a better understanding of it.

You can extend your abstract class or have it non-abstract.

Comment: Yes i understand it and mentioned it in my post above. I want to know a workaround to load some test data

Comment: @sharonHwk Which part of *You can extend your abstract class or have it non-abstract* needs more explanation to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're trying to do is Construct a new class. In that case, All you have to do is this:

```
public class Aclass {

    private String name;

    public Aclass(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to make it public. it should remain as abstract... and then i will create a test class, and try to load some test data to it

Comment: In that case, kosklain's answer is best.

Answer (score 0):

try to extends your class.....

public class B extends A {